# What does BindImageEx actually do?

Tags: windows, pe

[Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-bindimageex).
If I understand this correctly, this function pre-computes virtual addresses of imported DLLs and writes them to the IAT of an image (provided that `BIND_NO_UPDATE` is not set as parameter). My understanding is that you do this to an image (on file) to make it start faster.

- How does the windows loader know that the image has already been bound (and that it does not need to compute virtual addresses)?
- In the [DllCharacteristics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#dll-characteristics) in a PE file (in the optional header), there is a flag called `NO_BIND`. Does `BindImageEx` fail if this is set?
- What is the difference between `BIND_NO_BOUND_IMPORTS` and `BIND_NO_UPDATE` if the only updating it does is to the IAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Loader Knows the import is bound because bind process also writes a timestamp of the bounded module

suppose x.exe is bound to y.dll
y.dll has a TimeDateStamp in it peheader
when bound it writes the TimeDateStamp of y.dll in the
**_IMAGE_BOUND_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR**

```
0:000> dt ole32!_IMAGE_BOUND_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
   +0x000 TimeDateStamp    : Uint4B
   +0x004 OffsetModuleName : Uint2B
   +0x006 NumberOfModuleForwarderRefs : Uint2B
0:000>
```

The Api in Question has a callback StatusRoutine that will be called during the Binding Process
when you Pass noupdate the call back will still be called
you can do some inspection and may be take actions there but leave the exe un affected

BIND_NO_BOUND_IMPORTS  does not write a new ImportTable

[Quoting From Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-bindimageex)

> BIND_NO_BOUND_IMPORTS 0x00000001
>
> Do not generate a new import address table.
>
> BIND_NO_UPDATE 0x00000002
>
> Do not make changes to the file.